# Call username and password from google sheets in app inventor

Tags: google-sheets, app-inventor

I have currently got a simple login form that is allowing me to have users put into the coding blocks but I would to have many users data to be stored in google sheet with the column of username and pass.

I have tried implementing the is in list function but every time I work with it the app shows an error message and quits the app.

[image]

What would be the easiest way to look up the data from the google spreadsheet.

Comment: https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php Looking at your screenshot my suggestion for you is to restart at the beginning to learn App Inventor and do some tutorials first...

Comment: would it be easier to upload the csv file containing the username and password as assets and then access this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my simple fusiontable login example, which uses a 2 column table: user and password

[image]

But first do at least the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty) to learn how to work with fusiontables.